# Kendo UI Grid Remove the Outline of an HTML Element from the PDF Export

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI Grid that has a drop down element on the form. When I export to a PDF the selected value appears on the PDF but has the outline of the select element around it. When exporting to a pdf how can I remove the outline of the element?

Comment: You can add CSS classes as per your requirement. Like if you want to remove border for specific control you can set one class to that control and add CSS as below:



 `.k-pdf-export .noborder-in-pdf {
      border: none;
  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Diptee Hamdapurkar mentioned, you have the **.k-pdf-export** as base for this.

```
.k-pdf-export .k-grid td{
  border: 0;
}
```

here is the documentation.
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/pdfexport/content-styling/

Comment: Thanks.  In my case it was .k-pdf-export .k-grid select

Comment: glad it helped @dutchlab